# org-mode: per-exporter #+SELECT_TAGS & #+EXCLUDE_TAGS?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-tags, org-reveal

## Problem statement

In Emacs org-mode, I am looking for a way to define `#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS` (which defaults to `:noexport`) and `#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS` *on a per-exporter basis*, such that they apply only to specific exporters.

However, as far as I know, this functionality, which is detailed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24521309/23628503) to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520863/how-to-skip-some-specified-sections-when-exporting-org-file), applies globally to *all* org-mode exporters.

## Background

This problem arises from my desire to use the same org-mode source code to export to both,

1. regular HTML (for a verbose 'textbook-style' document), and
2. a Reveal.js presentation (which should be less verbose by excluding accordingly tagged sections). NB: For this I use [org-re-reveal](https://gitlab.com/oer/org-re-reveal), but my question is more generically about "different exporters" (could also concern HTML vs. LaTeX export, for example).

Essentially, I am trying to mimic [LaTeX Beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s "article mode", which allows the use of markers such as `\only<article>`, `\mode<presentation>`, `\mode<all>`, etc. to make certain content only appear in specific documents, all of which are compiled from the same source.

## What I imagine a solution to look like

My idea is to have org-mode code like the following:

```
* Some section
** Subsection content shows up in HTML, but not Reveal.js   :html:ignore:
- Foo
- Bla

** Subsection content shows up in Reveal.js, but not HTML   :reveal:ignore:
1. More
2. lists

** Subsection content shows up in both, HTML and Reveal.js  :reveal:html:ignore:
- Some
- text
```

This would require defining the tags `:html` and `:reveal` as *exporter-specific* `#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS`, but I don't know whether/how this is possible.

NB: The `:ignore` tag serves the purpose of excluding the subsection headings themselves in the export, whose sole purpose should be to control what is exported where. Of course if would be nice to include that functionality, too, in the definition of the `:html` and `:reveal` tags.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this

***Subtree tagged with `no_html` are skipped for `html` export***

***Subtree tagged with `no_rereveal` are skipped for `re-reveal` export***

[image: Subtree tag with no_html is skipped for html export]
on

```
#+options: ':nil *:t -:t ::t <:t H:3 \n:nil ^:t arch:headline
#+options: author:nil broken-links:mark c:nil creator:nil
#+options: d:(not "LOGBOOK") date:t e:t email:nil f:t inline:t num:t
#+options: p:nil pri:nil prop:nil stat:t tags:t tasks:t tex:t
#+options: timestamp:t title:t toc:t todo:t |:t
#+title: Skip Headings based on Export Backend
#+language: en
#+select_tags: export
#+exclude_tags: noexport
#+creator: Emacs 30.0.50 (Org mode 9.6.14)
#+cite_export:

[[https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80736/org-mode-per-exporter-select-tags-exclude-tags][org-mode: per-exporter ~#+SELECT_TAGS~ & ~#+EXCLUDE_TAGS?~]]

#+name: noexporttags
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results value pp :wrap src elisp
  (thread-last org-export-registered-backends
           (seq-map 'org-export-backend-name)
           (seq-map 'no-export-tag-for-backend)
           (seq-sort 'string>))
#+end_src

#+CAPTION: No export tags for all registered backedns
#+RESULTS: noexporttags

#+name: org-export-current-backend
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results value pp :wrap src elisp
org-export-current-backend
#+end_src

#+CAPTION: Current backend
#+RESULTS: org-export-current-backend

#+name: no-export-tag-for-backend
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results value pp :wrap src elisp
(no-export-tag-for-backend org-export-current-backend)
#+end_src

#+CAPTION: No export tag for current backend
#+RESULTS: no-export-tag-for-backend

#+name: versions
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results value pp :wrap src elisp
  (list (format "emacs-%s" emacs-version)
    (format "org-%s" org-version))
#+end_src

#+CAPTION:  Produced with 
#+RESULTS: versions

* Some section
** Subsection content shows up in Reveal.js, but not HTML   :no_html:
- Foo
- Bla

** Subsection content shows up in HTML, but not Reveal.js   :no_rereveal:
1. More
2. lists

** Subsection content shows up in neither, HTML nor Reveal.js  :no_rereveal:no_html:
- Some
- text
```

use this

```lisp
(defun no-export-tag-for-backend (backend)
  (thread-last backend
               symbol-name
               (replace-regexp-in-string "[^#%@_[:alnum:]]" "")
               (concat "no_")))

(advice-add 'org-export--skip-p :around
            (defun my-org-export--skip-p (orig-fun &rest args)
              (or (apply orig-fun args)
                  (pcase-let* ((`(,datum ,options ,selected ,excluded) args)
                               (tag-for-skipping-current-backend
                                (no-export-tag-for-backend org-export-current-backend)))
                    (pcase datum
                      ((and `(headline ,(map :tags) ,content)
                            (guard (seq-contains-p tags tag-for-skipping-current-backend)))
                       'skip))))))
```